# display a json array in html table

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display a JSON array in HTML which I get as response is

```
[
  {
    "New  upto 3 Yrs": 40.0,
    "Above 3 yr to 9 yrs": 35.0,
    "Above 9 yrs upto 12 yrs": 30.0
  }
]
```

here i am getting value undefined. (see snap shot  [image: output image])
How can I display this kind of JSON in HTML as a html table?

here is my script:

```
 success: function (data) {
            if (objMotorUnderwritingList.ddlVehicleType == "TW$") {
               // alert("hi TW$");
                if (data.jsDiscoundGridList != 0) {

                        var eachrow = "<tr>"
                                    + "<td>" + data.jsDiscoundGridList[0]["New upto 3 Yrs"] + "</td>"
                                    + "<td>" + data.jsDiscoundGridList[0]["Above 3 yr to 9 yrs"] + "</td>"
                                    + "<td>" + data.jsDiscoundGridList[0]["Above 9 yrs upto 12 yrs"] + "</td>"
                                    + "</tr>";
                        $('.tbody').html(eachrow);

                    }
                else {
                    ShowAlert("Something Wrong in TW");
                } 
            }}
```

Comment: looks like extra `spaces` (in keys) issue to me

Answer (score 1):

You have extra spaces in your property names, you can access the properties just fine if you change that:

Your code:

```js
let data = {
  jsDiscoundGridList: [{
    "New  upto 3 Yrs": 40.0,
    "Above 3 yr to 9 yrs": 35.0,
    "Above 9 yrs upto 12 yrs": 30.0
  }]
};

console.log(data.jsDiscoundGridList[0]["New upto 3 Yrs"]); // undefined
//                                         ^
```

With correct spacing:

```js
let data = {
  jsDiscoundGridList: [{
    "New  upto 3 Yrs": 40.0,
    "Above 3 yr to 9 yrs": 35.0,
    "Above 9 yrs upto 12 yrs": 30.0
  }]
};

console.log(data.jsDiscoundGridList[0]["New  upto 3 Yrs"]); // 40
//                                         ^^
```

Comment: with weird keys like this, I would rather go with Object.keys and read based on each key.

Comment: Yes, great idea!

Comment: thanx for the solution, I tried this but not getting value in HtML table, i need to bind this value into HTML Table